# Java looping through array - Optimization

Tags: java, string, for-loop, bioinformatics, fasta

I've got some Java code that runs quite the expected way, but it's taking some amount of time -some seconds- even if the job is just looping through an array.

The input file is a Fasta file as shown in the image below. The file I'm using is 2.9Mo, and there are some other Fasta file that can take up to 20Mo.

[image]

And in the code im trying to loop through it by bunches of threes, e.g: AGC TTT TCA ... etc The code has no functional sens for now but what I want is to append each Amino Acid to it's equivalent bunch of Bases. Example :

AGC - Ser / CUG Leu / ... etc

So what's wrong with the code ? and Is there any way to do it better ? Any optimization ? Looping through the whole String is taking some time, maybe just seconds, but need to find a better way to do it.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class fasta {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        File fastaFile;
        FileReader fastaReader;
        BufferedReader fastaBuffer = null;
        StringBuilder fastaString = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            fastaFile = new File("res/NC_017108.fna");
            fastaReader = new FileReader(fastaFile);
            fastaBuffer = new BufferedReader(fastaReader);
            String fastaDescription = fastaBuffer.readLine();
            String line = fastaBuffer.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                fastaString.append(line);
                line = fastaBuffer.readLine();
            }

            System.out.println(fastaDescription);
            System.out.println();
            String currentFastaAcid;

            for (int i = 0; i < fastaString.length(); i+=3) {
                currentFastaAcid = fastaString.toString().substring(i, i + 3);
                System.out.println(currentFastaAcid);
            }

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            fastaBuffer.close();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't know, why it's taking longer than expected, the only thing that I could mention is that the StringBuilder has the method "substring" built in, so you could avoid always creating a string (toString()) before taking out the subsequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big factor here is you are doing the call to substring over a new String each time.

Instead, use substring directly over the stringbuilder

```
for (int i = 0; i < fastaString.length(); i+=3){
    currentFastaAcid = fastaString.substring(i, i + 3);
    System.out.println(currentFastaAcid);
}
```

Also, instead of print the currentFastaAcid each time, save it into a list and print this list at the end

```
List<String> acids = new LinkedList<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < fastaString.length(); i+=3){
    currentFastaAcid = fastaString.substring(i, i + 3);
    acids.add(currentFastaAcid);
}

System.out.println(acids.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
currentFastaAcid = fastaString.toString().substring(i, i + 3);
```

Please replace with

```
currentFastaAcid = fastaString.substring(i, i + 3);
```

toString method of StringBuilder create new instance of String object every time you call it. It still contain a copy of all your large string. If you call substring directly from StringBuilder it will return a small copy of substring.
Also remove System.out.println if you don't really need it.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem besides the debug output surely is, that you are creating a new String with your completely read data from the file in each iteration of your loop:

```
currentFastaAcid = fastaString.toString().substring(i, i + 3);
```

fastaString.toString() will give the same result in each iteration and therefore is redundant. Get it outside the loop and you will surely save some seconds runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from suggested optimization in the serial code, I will go for parallel processing to reduce time further. If you have really big file, you can divide the work of reading file and processing read-lines, in separate threads. That way, when one thread is busy reading nextline from large file, other thread can process read-lines and print them on console.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the

```
System.out.println(currentFastaAcid);
```

line in the for loop, you will gain quite decent time.